# optimization calculus, cannot find restriction, I am stuck!

Tags: calculus, optimization

A capsule formed by a cylinder and two half spheres on the top and the bottom have a minimal volume of $\pi / 12$. What is the height and radius of the capsule? The volume is $$\pi r^2 (4 \times \pi/3 + h ) = 12 / \pi$$ This is usually derived. I cannot find a restriction to plug in the first formula.

Please help me solve this!

Comment: You made few mistakes in your equation. You should have
$$
\pi r^2(4/3 r+h)=\pi/12
$$
So 
$$
4/3 r^3+r^2 h= 1/12;
$$

Comment: Yeah, that was the initial equation, sorry. I'm still missing a restriction, or something to plug in my initial equation. :)

Comment: What does it mean "minimal volume" -  minimal with respect to what?

Comment: Like, find the smallest/optimal combination of radius and height that amounts to fill the capsule with (12/pi) of volume. The teacher said we usually have a nice formula to derive at the beginning, but we have 2 variables in it (in this case radius and height). We usually have a restriction which gives a numerical value to one of the two variables to replace in the first equation before deriving. Or a relationship between the two shapes, I don't know.

Comment: I am asking again. What does it mean "smallest/optimal combination? Smallest/optimal with respect to what if the volume is fixed? This is the key issue you have here.

Comment: I don't know, this is all the info I have.. :/

Comment: You or your teacher missed something.

Comment: I can post a picture if you can read french. Alternatively, I'll translate word by word the problem?

Comment: OK, let's do this

Comment: Full question: http://i.gyazo.com/2bcf901e9ebff4ec5e683dda465ebab1.png

Translation: Given a capsule formed by a straight cylinder of height H, where H>=0, and the extremities are half circles of the same radius as the cylinder. Determine the dimensions of the cylinder and the half spheres in such a way that the quantity of material necessary to the fabrication of the capsule is 'minimal' if we want to insert pi/12 sybstance to fill: B)the whole capsule. (ignored A, will do it after B).

Comment: Teacher just gave a precision by email cause it didn't make sense: He wants to minimize the AREA!!! :D

Comment: Now it has the perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

The area of the capsule $S(r,h)$ is :
$$
S(r,h)=2\pi r h +4\pi r^2
$$

You have constraint
$$
4/3r^3+r^2h=1/12;
$$
So $rh=1/12/r-4/3 r^2$ and the area as the function of $r$ is
$$
S(r,h)=2\pi r h +4\pi r^2=2\pi(rh+2r^2)=G(r)=2\pi(1/(12r)-4/3r^2+2r^2)=2\pi(2/3 r^2-1/(12r))
$$
Now you have to minimize $G(r)$.